# New ios chrome version will persist pull-to-refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, google-chrome

I need to cancel the **ios version** of chrome's pull-to-refresh for my website.

Currently chrome 69.0.3497.105 doesn't support the css *overscroll-behavior*

I've tried to implement these existing solutions and could not get them to work:

- http://w3bits.com/prevent-chrome-pull-to-refresh-css/
- [Disable Chrome's pull-to-refresh on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50763813/disable-chromes-pull-to-refresh-on-iphone)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/prevent-pull-refresh

It still does a pull to refresh on an iPhone. I need confirmation, can anyone get the solutions posted above to work with the newer chrome versions now? Is there a pollyfill that can be used for overscroll-behavior with chrome ios or what alternative can be used to cancel the pull-to-refresh behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the project I was working on had used a cdn to default events to be passive.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/default-passive-events"></script>
```

After realizing this and commenting out the cdn snippet for testing, I found that the solution of:

[Disable Chrome's pull-to-refresh on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51176339/3859456)

does indeed work.